# 前の行と同じであれば空欄になっているCSVテキストのセルを全部埋めたい

Tags: ruby

国、州/県、都市を定義した、こんなCSVテキストがあったとします。

```
日本,東京,新宿
,,渋谷
,兵庫,神戸
アメリカ,カリフォルニア,サンフランシスコ
,,ロサンゼルス
```

データは予めソートされていて、国や州が前のデータと同じであれば空欄になっています。

このテキストを変換して、セルを全部埋めるプログラムを作りたいと思っています。
すなわち、期待するのは以下のようなアウトプットです。

```
日本,東京,新宿
日本,東京,渋谷
日本,兵庫,神戸
アメリカ,カリフォルニア,サンフランシスコ
アメリカ,カリフォルニア,ロサンゼルス
```

とりあえず僕の方で愚直にこんなロジックを考えたんですが、ブロックの外で定義する`current_country`、`current_state`や、`if country.size > 0 ... end` がDRYになってない感じが自分でもちょっとしっくりきません。

```
  def fill_blank(csv_text)
    current_country, current_state = nil, nil
    csv_text.lines.map { |line|
      country, state, city = line.chomp.split(',')
      if country.size > 0
        current_country = country
      end
      if state.size > 0
        current_state = state
      end
      [current_country, current_state, city].join(',')
    }.join("\n")
  end
```

もうちょっと短くてわかりやすい、スマートなロジックは作れないでしょうか？
Railsで動かすのでActiveSupportのメソッドを使うのもOKです。
参考までにテストコード付きのサンプルコードを載せておきます。

```
require 'test/unit'

class FillBlankTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def fill_blank(csv_text)
    current_country, current_state = nil, nil
    csv_text.lines.map { |line|
      country, state, city = line.chomp.split(',')
      if country.size > 0
        current_country = country
      end
      if state.size > 0
        current_state = state
      end
      [current_country, current_state, city].join(',')
    }.join("\n")
  end

  def test_fill_blank
    input = <<-TEXT
日本,東京,新宿
,,渋谷
,兵庫,神戸
アメリカ,カリフォルニア,サンフランシスコ
,,ロサンゼルス
    TEXT

    output = <<-TEXT.chomp
日本,東京,新宿
日本,東京,渋谷
日本,兵庫,神戸
アメリカ,カリフォルニア,サンフランシスコ
アメリカ,カリフォルニア,ロサンゼルス
    TEXT

    assert_equal output, fill_blank(input)
  end
end
```

みなさんのアイデアをお待ちしています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

前の行をまるごと保存して、文字列が空なら前の行の項目を使う方法を考えてみました。

```
def fill_blank(csv_text)
  prev = []

  csv_text.each_line.map do |line|
    row = line.chomp.split ","
    prev = row.zip(prev).map{|a, b| a.empty? ? b : a }
    prev * ","
  end * "\n"
end
```

CSVライブラリを使えばもう少し短くなります。(空文字列はnilになります)

```
require 'csv'

def fill_blank(csv_text)
  prev = []

  CSV.parse(csv_text).map do |row|
    prev = row.zip(prev).map{|a, b| a || b }
    prev * ","
  end * "\n"
end
```

Comment: おお、CSVライブラリ良いですね！ただ、ローカル変数がちょっと浮いてる気がするので、injectで無理矢理(?)消してみました。 https://gist.github.com/JunichiIto/d4aa039f4b8aad040453

Answer (score 0):

Ruby暦1週間ほどなため
文法におかしな点があるかもしれませんが
ご容赦ください

行列の入れ替え(transpose)を使えば
スマートになるかと思いチャレンジしてみました

。。。結果可読性が落ちただけな気が
アイディアの足しになれば幸いです

```
def fill_blank(csv_text)
    shwo = ""
    csv_text.lines.map{|line| line.chomp.split(',')}
                .transpose.map{|row| row.map{|i|
                    shwo = i.empty? ? shwo : i
                    shwo
                }}.transpose.map{|line|line.join(',')}.join("\n")
end
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！ただ、ちょっと僕には改善されたようには見えないですね。。。せっかく回答してもらったのにすいません ><

Answer (score 0):

CSVの`converters`に値が`nil`なら前の行の値を引き継ぐようなカスタムコンバータを指定するとよいのではないでしょうか。

```ruby
require 'csv'

def fill_blank(csv_text)
  prev_vals = []
  preview_row = proc do |field, field_info|
    prev_vals[field_info.index] = field.nil? ? prev_vals[field_info.index] : field
  end

  CSV.generate do |csv|
    CSV.parse(csv_text, converters: [preview_row]) do |row|
      csv << row
    end
  end
end
```

Ruby 2.1.x以前であればうまく実行出来ると思います。

※Ruby 2.2.xではCSVライブラリの挙動が変わっているようなのでバグ報告しました

[Bug #11126: CSV field converters doesn't attempt to convert nil value. - Ruby trunk - Ruby Issue Tracking System](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11126)